# How to solve problem with reverse in Python?

Tags: python, reverse

Task condition this

[image]

My code is working but I am getting failed message
[image: My code is working but I am getting failed message]

why am I error? **Please give me help!**

Comment: Please post as text, not images.

Comment: You're reversing the words, not the whole text.

Comment: Try your code with the example input.

Comment: The expected result with your input is `"txet desrever a ton si siht"`

Comment: Are you aware of the built-in [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function?

Comment: what's the point of converting this to a list, reversing the list, and re-joining the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just use slicing to reverse the string?

slicing works like this:

```
text[start:end:step]
```

to reverse a string you can use a -1 step..

```
reversed = text[::-1]

print(reversed)

txet desrever a ton si siht
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand task condition but now I u-nd

Answer (score 1):

You're asked to simply reverse a string so you could do this:

```
string = 'again'
def reverse(s):
    return s[::-1]

print(reverse(string)) #will print niaga
```

The notation used is called string indexing and/or slicing with negative stepping. The syntax is str[start:end:step]. With start and end empty you're taking a slice that includes the whole string (all characters) and with step as -1 (negative) you you're starting at the end of the string and stepping toward the beginning without skipping any characters.

Comment: @DerekEden yes while I was writing mine. The OP asks for a function called reverse(x) so mine is more inline with the OPs requirement no?.

Comment: well technically the OP asks why they were getting and error and for help...their screenshot shows a homework problem asking for a function

Answer (score -1):

Your code is mostly right except for the `x.split(" ")` part. If you want to reverse a given string here is the solution:

```py
string = "again"

def reverse(x):
  x = list(x)
  x.reverse()
  return "".join(x)

print(reverse(string))
```

Comment: your desired output can be achieved in one step..this uses 3 and is a work around way to do something slicing already handles

Comment: @DerekEden Yahyoxon already had a solution that he wished to use and I just fixed it for him. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: it's worse to help someone patch together the wrong way of doing something then to show them the right way